# Why did Shifrah give Moses back to Pharaoh's daughter?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, parashas-shemos, shemot-exodus

Parashat Shemot, Chapter 2, states:

> וַתַּ֥הַר הָאִשָּׁ֖ה וַתֵּ֣לֶד בֵּ֑ן וַתֵּ֤רֶא אֹתוֹ֙ כִּי־ט֣וֹב ה֔וּא
>   וַֽתִּצְפְּנֵ֖הוּ שְׁלֹשָׁ֥ה יְרָחִֽים׃ ג וְלֹא־יָכְלָ֣ה עוֹד֮
>   הַצְּפִינוֹ֒ וַתִּֽקַּֽח־לוֹ֙ תֵּ֣בַת גֹּ֔מֶא וַתַּחְמְרָ֥ה בַחֵמָ֖ר
>   וּבַזָּ֑פֶת וַתָּ֤שֶׂם בָּהּ֙ אֶת־הַיֶּ֔לֶד וַתָּ֥שֶׂם בַּסּ֖וּף
>   עַל־שְׂפַ֥ת הַיְאֹֽר׃ ד וַתֵּתַצַּ֥ב אֲחֹת֖וֹ מֵרָחֹ֑ק לְדֵעָ֕ה
>   מַה־יֵּעָשֶׂ֖ה לֽוֹ׃ ה וַתֵּ֤רֶד בַּת־פַּרְעֹה֙ לִרְחֹ֣ץ עַל־הַיְאֹ֔ר
>   וְנַעֲרֹתֶ֥יהָ הֹלְכֹ֖ת עַל־יַ֣ד הַיְאֹ֑ר וַתֵּ֤רֶא אֶת־הַתֵּבָה֙
>   בְּת֣וֹךְ הַסּ֔וּף וַתִּשְׁלַ֥ח אֶת־אֲמָתָ֖הּ וַתִּקָּחֶֽהָ ו
>   וַתִּפְתַּח֙ וַתִּרְאֵ֣הוּ אֶת־הַיֶּ֔לֶד וְהִנֵּה־נַ֖עַר בֹּכֶ֑ה
>   וַתַּחְמֹ֣ל עָלָ֔יו וַתֹּ֕אמֶר מִיַּלְדֵ֥י הָֽעִבְרִ֖ים זֶֽה׃ ז
>   וַתֹּ֣אמֶר אֲחֹתוֹ֮ אֶל־בַּת־פַּרְעֹה֒ הַאֵלֵ֗ךְ וְקָרָ֤אתִי לָךְ֙
>   אִשָּׁ֣ה מֵינֶ֔קֶת מִ֖ן הָעִבְרִיֹּ֑ת וְתֵינִ֥ק לָ֖ךְ אֶת־הַיָּֽלֶד׃ ח
>   וַתֹּֽאמֶר־לָ֥הּ בַּת־פַּרְעֹ֖ה לֵ֑כִי וַתֵּ֙לֶךְ֙ הָֽעַלְמָ֔ה
>   וַתִּקְרָ֖א אֶת־אֵ֥ם הַיָּֽלֶד׃ ט וַתֹּ֧אמֶר לָ֣הּ בַּת־פַּרְעֹ֗ה
>   הֵילִ֜יכִי אֶת־הַיֶּ֤לֶד הַזֶּה֙ וְהֵינִקִ֣הוּ לִ֔י וַאֲנִ֖י אֶתֵּ֣ן
>   אֶת־שְׂכָרֵ֑ךְ וַתִּקַּ֧ח הָאִשָּׁ֛ה הַיֶּ֖לֶד וַתְּנִיקֵֽהוּ׃ י
>   וַיִגְדַּ֣ל הַיֶּ֗לֶד וַתְּבִאֵ֙הוּ֙ לְבַת־פַּרְעֹ֔ה וַֽיְהִי־לָ֖הּ
>   לְבֵ֑ן וַתִּקְרָ֤א שְׁמוֹ֙ מֹשֶׁ֔ה וַתֹּ֕אמֶר כִּ֥י מִן־הַמַּ֖יִם
>   מְשִׁיתִֽהוּ׃
>
> 2 The woman conceived and bore a son; and when she saw how beautiful he was, she hid him for three months.
>   3 When she could hide him no longer, she got a wicker basket for him and caulked it with bitumen and pitch. She put the child into it and placed it among the reeds by the bank of the Nile.
>   4 And his sister stationed herself at a distance, to learn what would befall him.
>   5 The daughter of Pharaoh came down to bathe in the Nile, while her maidens walked along the Nile. She spied the basket among the reeds and sent her slave girl to fetch it.
>   6 When she opened it, she saw that it was a child, a boy crying. She took pity on it and said, “This must be a Hebrew child.”
>   7 Then his sister said to Pharaoh’s daughter, “Shall I go and get you a Hebrew nurse to suckle the child for you?”
>   8 And Pharaoh’s daughter answered, “Yes.” So the girl went and called the child’s mother.
>   9 And Pharaoh’s daughter said to her, “Take this child and nurse it for me, and I will pay your wages.” So the woman took the child and nursed it.
>   10 When the child grew up, she brought him to Pharaoh’s daughter, who made him her son. She named him Moses, explaining, “I drew him out of the water."

Shifrah (Yocheved) was very clever; she was able to prevent the Jewish baby boys, most notably her own son Moses, from being killed according to Pharaoh's command. So why didn't she find some way to hide or keep her son Moses after nursing him? Why--other than in deference to the Hand of Providence--did she give him back to Bitya, under whose care he would almost certainly grow up in a non-Jewish environment, if not be killed?

Comment: Relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51326/3

Comment: `under whose care he would almost certainly grow up in a non-Jewish environment,`  The differences between the Israelites and others would presumably not have been nearly as acute then, before Sinai, as they would be today. || `if not be killed?` Tucking him away under the aegis of Bitya seems like as good a tactic as any to protect him. || Speaking of Bityah, note that there is no one in Tanakh (or Chazal AFAIK) named Batyah. [the name is Bityah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5782/8775).

Comment: @mevaqesh "The differences between the Israelites and others would presumably not have been nearly as acute then, before Sinai, as they would be today." I can assure you that not everyone would agree with this presumption, nor that a culture of idolatry is not so different from a culture of monotheism

Comment: Not enough for an answer but apparently there is a medresh that Bityah was in the process of converting to Judaism and--maybe I am getting this wrong--her placing Moishe's basket in the water was actually her mikveh dip. Maybe Shifrah had the horse sense to realize that her child would be safe with BItyah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to be noted after careful reading of the verses, that the first decree that Pharaoh had concerning the Jewish males was first that the midwives kill male babies during birth *only afterwards* when Pharaoh saw that is was not working did he order that the male babies were  to be thrown in the Nile.

[Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.1.22?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) on 1:22 quoting Sotah 12a says that the second decree of Pharaoh (of throwing the male babies into the Nile) applied both to Jewish and Egyptian babies. So removing Moses permanently from Pharaoh's household would present a danger to him weather it was known that he was Jewish or Egyptian.

To say that Yoceved would be able to hide Moses would be challenging being that [the reason why Moses was sent in a basket on the Nile was because his parents could not hide him](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2?lang=bi). So the question asked should have been started earlier (See [Rashi 2:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.2.3.1&lang2=en) for an answer)

Hope this helps.