# The miraculous nature of the incident with Bas Paroh and baby Moshe; why is it not mentioned in the text?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos

[Shemos 2 (5 – 11)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). To escape the decree of Paroh to kill Jewish male babies, Yocheved places her son in a basket in the water. None other than Paroh's daughter discovers him and saves him.  Paroh's daughter agrees to Miriam's suggestion that she find a Jewish wet-nurse to feed the baby and the result is that Paroh's daughter is paying Yocheved to nurse her own son. This seems to be a miraculous turn of events. The Chumash makes no mention of the  **miraculous nature** of the incident nor of the feelings of Yocheved and Miriam.

Why is there no mention of the miraculous nature of the incident with Bas Paroh and baby Moshe in the text. Do any of the meforshim speak about it?

Related: [Why did Shifrah give Moses back to Pharaoh's daughter?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75692/why-did-shifrah-give-moses-back-to-pharaohs-daughter)

[How did Paro's daughter explain suddenly having a child?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88346/how-did-paros-daughter-explain-suddenly-having-a-child)

Comment: Theres plenty of miracles mentioned in midrashim that aren't in the text. The Torah doesn't just say all the miracles. The Shela says the Torah writes things we can learn from on a practical level.

Comment: The miracle **is** mentioned; it is not remarked on by the text.

Comment: You're right, every midrash is hinted in the text. The reason why it's not written explictly, the Shela explains since one can't learn from it.

Comment: I suggest that we can learn from it. That is that however bad the situation is, Hashem can bring about a salvation. The salvation moreover can come for the most unexpected source and against all reasonable expectations. Who would have thought that Paroh's daughter would pay Moshe's mother  to nurse him when Paroh had decreed that all Jewish babies should bedrowned?

Comment: You see that concept here more than the rest of the Torah?

Comment: I think Reb Chaim Shmuelevitz says it was not a miracle. It was a mind-over-matter thing effected by Basya.

Comment: Can you source that @pcoz please?

Comment: See Ramban Beraishis 46:15 for a general discussion of unremarked miracles https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.46.15?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=he

Comment: @Shlomy the miracle mentioned here can be found in the plain text no midrash necessary

Comment: @ezra the one who wrote the question disagrees with that.

Comment: @Shlomy : No I do not disagree. The miracle is clearly stated in the text. I ask why the text does not mention the miraculous nature of the incident nor the feelings of Yocheved and Miriam.

Answer (score 0):

The verses say that Miriam, Moshe's sister, stood watch to see what would happen with Moshe. When the daughter of Pharaoh pulled Moshe from the water, Miriam suggested Yocheved as a nurse. So it was not so much a miracle as a result of Miriam's dedication.